# app:dexDebug exception while creating sample appliaction on azure mobileclientservice

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am creating sample application to communicate with GCM.
i am able to register with GCM and create notification hub and  any notification on hub , app gets notified with notification .

Now i want to send data to hub .
I am using MobileServiceClient with url and pass key .when i do gradle sync i get this error.

Code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Registration;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsManager;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;


 regId = gcmObj.register(AppConstant.GOOGLE_PROJ_ID);
 hub = new NotificationHub(HubName, HubListenConnectionString, getApplicationContext());
 Registration registration= hub.register(regId, "e9fa0e95-346f-4ed8-b854-df6251c50525");


mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                            CLOUD_URL,
                            CLOUD_PASSKEY,
                            this);

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/notification-hubs-0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/notifications-1.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2'

}
```

Please help me on resolving issue .

```
Error:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'
```

Error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 2

Comment: Error message:    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: I am facing the excat problem. DId you manage to solve it ? Could you please help me?